# Requires extended permission: publish_actions for users even after approved publish_actions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

Hi I have a 'publish_actions' approved Facebook live App.

It perfectly works for developer accounts and can upload image.

But when any normal user accessing this app, it shows a:

> fatal (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Can any one suggest me solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Approved in review means that your app *can* ask normal users for a permission.

It does of course not mean, that the current app user has automatically *granted* that permission to your app. You still need to ask them for it, via the login flow.

Comment: i have ask that once in login time, and when the time of post image it didn't show.

Comment: Debug the access token, to see if it actually contains the permission.

Comment: how can i get the access token ?

Comment: when i debug access token of developer accounts it shows 
email, publish_actions, public_profile permissions, but normal user shows email, public_profile ! how can i sort it out ? please help me

Comment: Then you did not ask the user for the permission, or they declined it.

Comment: How can i ask for the permisssion ?

Comment: By sending them through the login flow.

Comment: this is my code section `$permissions = ['email','publish_actions'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(URL.'shareimage.php', $permissions);
    header("Location:".$loginUrl);`

Comment: If you have the permission approved, then the user should be asked for it with this code - unless they have been asked before already, and declined the permission. In that case, you need to add a special parameter to the login dialog call, to re-ask for that permission. (But for testing you can also just remove the app completely from the user’s FB settings, that cleans the slate, and they will be asked again next time.)

Comment: what kind of special parameter ? i have cleared the fb settings and re-login and shows permissions one for public_profile another for publish_actions and both are grant ,shows the same error at the time of post image

Comment: Are you sure you are using that very same access token at the point where you are trying to make the post? Please edit your question to include relevant parts of code.